# How to update an image in the get_template_directory_uri()?

Tags: image, header, parallax

I need to update the header image on the front page of our website. I found the code in the Theme Editor for the header.php. The current image link is there but I can't find the template directory to add the new image to be able to swap them out. How would I go about finding the template directory to add in / update the image?

Old Photo: /images/woolpower-home-bg.jpg

New Photo: https://woolpowerus.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/Header-Kollag-2021.jpg

```
<?php if (is_front_page()): ?>
    <header class="home-banner jarallax">
    
        <img class="jarallax-img" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/woolpower-home-bg.jpg" alt="woolpower" title="woolpower">

        <div class="control-content">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="box-content">
                    <h1>Why Woolpower?</h1>
                    <p> Because we manufacture underwear and reinforcement garments all the way from yarn to finished product in Östersund, Sweden. We are a company that takes responsibility for people, animals and nature. The clothes are sewn to last and adapted to extreme weather conditions. But at the same time, they should keep you warm in your everyday life.  </p>
                
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    
    </header>
```

Could I use -

```
<img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ? 
 >/uploads/2012/09/Header-Kollag-2021.jpg" />
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `get_template_directory_uri` is returning `https://woolpowerus.com/wp-content/themes/targetmarket` so `src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/uploads/2012/09/Header-Kollag-2021.jpg"` would point to the wrong location.

You could re-upload the image under the theme's folder or use `src="https://woolpowerus.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/Header-Kollag-2021.jpg"`